# Unable to build App after adding Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

So I'm having a bit of a odd error. Since adding Google play services to a project it now will no long build. It will sit at 99% launching eclipse will become unresponsive and give a error Java Heap Error.

[image]

If I remove the play services the app builds fine. I've never had this is before and I've successfully created and built apps with google play services before.

This is even happening on previous app that I have finished developing and have released. The issue isn't with code and the Play Services on old apps has not been tampered with so the adding process will have been correct.

I've not changed any setting on eclipse. Can any help? Why can i no longer build/launch apps with google play services.

Comment: Eh... why are you using Eclipse? You should be using Android Studio since a lot of time.

Comment: It's just the tool I have always used. I'll look at moving to Android Studio but still would like a solution to this problem

Comment: I don't think you can fix that... Google remove the support for Eclipse a few months ago and Play Service now is require with version 7 and 8 (not going to work over Eclipse)

Comment: Have you tried increasing memory allocated to Eclipse?

Comment: What @FarooqArshed is true... that's normally and issue with Play Services and Eclipse. Again, you should move to AS to full compatibility.

Comment: Thanks guys, @FarooqArshed that was correct if you post as a answer I will accept it. Mariano Zorrilla thank you for the advise. I have downloaded android studio future projects will be made with it :)

Comment: Try, in your spare time, to use the Android Studio importer :) is really good! In 30min you'll have all your project working there. I use to have the same issues with Eclipse and not any more with AS. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing memory allocated to Eclipse..

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: Try to add a little details on how to do this for OP.